# How to prevent alignment changes in beamer due to changing line height in list items?

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment, lists

Consider this simple setup:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{block}{The One}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item \only<1>{This is a tall row.}
              \only<2>{This one is ganglier.}
      \end{itemize}
    \end{block}

    \begin{block}{The Other}
      Just a regular block that should stay where it is.
    \end{block}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The problem is now that the computed box heights apparently change (note that the tall row does not have a "deep" letter, the gangly one does) and the blocks get aligned differently. This creates bad slide transition effects:

[image]

My current hack is to add `\phantom{g}` to the tall row.

Is there a less hacky solution, preferably one that gets rid of the effect globally?

Nota bene: this does *not* happen without the surrounding list! That is, if you have

```
\begin{block}{The One}
    \only<1>{This is a tall row.}
    \only<2>{This one is ganglier.}
\end{block}
```

we get:

[image]

Comment: change the line skip value to something larger?

Comment: @percusse Increasing `\lineskip` from `1.0pt` to `1ex` changes all kinds of things, but the issue remains.

Comment: That is presumably down to how minipage cuts up the space below a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a well known (and documented; cf. section 9.5 of the `beamer` documentation) effect with overlays and I am afraid there's no general solution. Two possible solutions are to use `\strut`s for the `\item`s or to use an `overprint` or an `overlayarea` environment:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{block}{The One}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item \only<1>{\strut This is a tall row.}
              \only<2>{\strut This one is ganglier.}
      \end{itemize}
    \end{block}

    \begin{block}{The Other}
      Just a regular block that should stay where it is.
    \end{block}

    \begin{block}{The One}
    \begin{overprint}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item \only<1>{This is a tall row.}
              \only<2>{This one is ganglier.}
      \end{itemize}
    \end{overprint}
    \end{block}

    \begin{block}{The Other}
      Just a regular block that should stay where it is.
    \end{block}

  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Assume I redefined `\only` to always do `\strut` at the beginning. What issues would that cause?

Comment: @Raphael for texts spanning more than one line it would be useless since the `\strut` will only affect the first line. This    `\begin{block}{The One}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item \only<1>{\strut This is a tall row.}
              \only<2>{\strut This one is ganglier and some more text some more text some more text some more text ggg}
      \end{itemize}
    \end{block}` shows that it would be no general solution to add `\strut` just at the beginning.